# jquery dynamic id selector, remove then add class

Tags: jquery, dynamic, jquery-selectors, addclass, removeclass

I have a table, with rows which all have a cell of a div with a dynamically generated id in the format of btn-insertidhere.

When the table row is selected, I want to select this div id, then remove a class and change it to another one. This is down to me wanting to have a button image change from an add symbol to a delete symbol which when clicked.

javascript code:

```
  $('*[class^=day] tbody tr[id^=band]').live('click', function() {
        var DivId = $(this).find('div.add').attr('id');
        alert(DivId);

        $('DivId').removeClass('add').addClass('del');
        $('table#fri_myTimes tbody').append($(this)).fadeIn(1000);
        return false;
});
```

This is an html snippet of the dynamically generated code:

```
<tr id="band-Modest-Mouse">
<td>Modest Mouse</td>
<td>15:25:00</td>
<td>16:10:00</td>
<td>45</td>
<td><div id="btn-Modest-Mouse" class="add">&nbsp;</div></td>
</tr>
```

As you can see i want to change the 'add' class to a delete 'class'. All the table rows on the table is generated like this, so as you can see i've gone for the wildcard approach, which seems to work because the alert shown, shows the correct div id. I just need to change the class!

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You either have to get the jq object for the div by removing the '.attr(id)' part

```
var DivId = $(this).find('div.add');
...
$(DivId).removeClass('add').addClass('del');
```

or add a # in the divId selector

```
$("#" + DivId).removeClass('add').addClass('del');
```

Comment: BOTH SOLUTIONS WORKED! Thank you very much. Out of curiosity, which way is better? The .find() method or get the .attr(id) method?

Comment: Is better to use the first one... with the find you already have the div wrapped in a jquery object, you don't need to find it again, as you would in the second case...

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the quotes around DivId.  It's a variable name and shouldn't be in quotes.  As such:

```
$(DivId).removeClass('add').addClass('del');
```

Comment: It retains the 'add' class when it appends to the new table. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry about that, Jaime answered before I could correct this.

Answer (score 1):

Since your variable DivId is a jquery object, you don't need the `$()` at all:

```
DivId.removeClass('add').addClass('del');
```